# Zend Architecture optimal use in website

Tags: zend-framework

I have a site that needs a user side and a admin side.

I can create two index files(dispatch) one for each. like site/index.php and site/admin/index.php. Both side will use same zend library and models. All other things like (controller,view,layout etc...) will be separate. This will be like application/controllers and application/admin/controllers

Or I can use the admin panel as a module .

Which will be the best. As I may need to change the path of the admin panel this may be site/xyz/something/admin and may be need to do some specific work only for admin side.

NOW What zend library class I should use for following concerns.

1. Date Validatation and verification ( server side checks)
2. SQl injection ( use of '?' in sql select/insert/update statement instead of putting variabledirectly)
3. URL encryption
4. URL rewrite ( Zend routes is the best one for this)
5. File uploading
6. Html forms (use zend forms that have in build in feature for validation but it is not usefull in all the cases. I prefer to use form tags directly)

Advise on this and suggest if you have more ...

Answer (score 0):

1. Zend_Validate_Date
2. Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::quote
3. Zend_View_Helper_Url
4. Zend_Controller_Router_Abstract
5. Zend_Form_Element_File
6. Zend_Form has some problems, but it is very flexible. Do you know that you can handle complex layout by rendering each element separately : http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/215-Rendering-Zend_Form-decorators-individually.html